# tuple index out of range - detectron2

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, detectron

I saved the model named final_model that I trained in the output file on colab, but it gives a tuple index out of range error. How can I solve this error. In addition, I want to import the output file from google drive.
How can I edit the code in the picture.

```
#visualize training data
my_dataset_train_metadata = MetadataCatalog.get("my_dataset_train")
dataset_dicts = DatasetCatalog.get("my_dataset_train")

import random
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import Visualizer

for d in random.sample(dataset_dicts, 3):
    img = cv2.imread(d["file_name"])
    visualizer = Visualizer(img[:, :, ::-1], metadata=my_dataset_train_metadata, scale=0.5)
    vis = visualizer.draw_dataset_dict(d)
    cv2_imshow(vis.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])
    from detectron2.data import DatasetCatalog, MetadataCatalog, build_detection_test_loader
    from detectron2.evaluation import COCOEvaluator, inference_on_dataset
```

---

```
#train

from detectron2.config import get_cfg
import os

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-Detection/faster_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x.yaml"))
cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN = ("my_dataset_train",)
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ("my_dataset_val",)

cfg.DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS = 2
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = model_zoo.get_checkpoint_url("COCO-Detection/faster_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x.yaml") 
cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 2
cfg.SOLVER.BASE_LR = 0.001


cfg.SOLVER.WARMUP_ITERS = 3
cfg.SOLVER.STEPS = []
cfg.SOLVER.GAMMA = 0.05




cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE = 128
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 33 

cfg.TEST.EVAL_PERIOD = 500


os.makedirs(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)
trainer = CocoTrainer(cfg)
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
trainer.train()
```

---

```
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = os.path.join(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, "model_final.pth")
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.3

pred = DefaultPredictor(cfg) #predictor
eva = COCOEvaluator("test_dataset", cfg, False, output_dir = "./output/") # evaluator
val_loader = build_detection_test_loader(cfg, "test_dataset")
inference_on_dataset(trainer.model, val_loader, Eva)
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiJTQ.png)

Comment: Please show the relevant code (you are not showing the line where the error occurs!) **and** the complete error backtrace *in text format*. Ideally, you should show how `cfg.DATASETS.TEST` was defined.

Comment: Please edit your question by adding this code snippet, it will be easier for us to read. Also, what is `MetaDataCatalog`?